# Finding Extremas of $|x|$.

Tags: multivariable-calculus, optimization

I'm trying to find the extrema of$\mod(x)$ but I'm not being able to do so. My attempt:

$f(x, y) = |x|$

$f_{xx} = 0, f_{yy} = 0, f_{xy} = 0.$

So, $D(x, y) = 0$. And second derivative test isn't helping me at all.

Comment: Extrema are attained at critical points OR at points where the function is not differentiable.

Comment: I'm not being able to find critical points. Second derivative test can't tell me anything since it is zero. Therefore, I must solve it graphically or something.

Comment: You can't find: there's none. When defined $f_x=1$.

Comment: The second derivative is *not* zero when $x=0$. It is not differentiable there.

Answer (score 2):

A hint:

Forget about calculus and go at the problem in a pedestrian fashion. Get an intuitive picture how the graph of $f$ (a surface over the $(x,y)$-plane) looks like, and it will soon enough become obvious what the extrema of $f$ are.

Comment: It looks as if absolute minima is 0 (zero) and absolute maxima is infinity.